# Add Multiple-Contact Messages Widget To Home Screen

Tags: app-widgets, instant-messaging

Is there a way to add a messages widget to the home screen for a conversation with multiple contacts?

Comment: What do you mean by 'multiple contacts conversation' ?

Comment: A group text. Sorry, that was confusing verbiage; I used that phrase because when adding the text widget you select a contact, but as far as I can tell there's no way to select multiple contacts.

Comment: Which messaging app are you using?

Comment: Google Messages.

Comment: But now I can't find any widget provided by Google Messages app. Previously it was there, but after the recent update, I can no longer find any widget.

Comment: You're right, it's actually a contacts - direct message widget, which is using my default messages app, which is Google Messages.

Comment: What is the name of the contacts app?

Comment: It looks like com.samsung.android.contacts.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use Samsung phone. So, please wait for the attention of a Samsung phone user.